# quickly extract the contents of an xml tag in php

Tags: php, xml, scribd

Scribd's API returns XML, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rsp stat="ok"><thumbnail_url>http://imgv2-4.scribdassets.com/img/word_document/60906103/111x142/79c5e6bab7/1327030759</thumbnail_url></rsp>
```

is there a way to quickly, say in one or two lines, get the contents of `thumbnail_url`, that is `http://imgv2-4.scribdassets.com/img/word_document/60906103/111x142/79c5e6bab7/1327030759`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string_data);
$url = (string) $xml->thumbnail_url;
```

Comment: Yes, simplexml is the simplest way, ;)

Comment: Is it necessary to prepend `(string)`? Why?

Comment: @Norse: `$xml->thumbnail_url` returns a `SimpleXMLElement` object with a `__toString` method, which returns the node's text content.  Prepending `(string)` gets rid of the object and just leaves the string value.  This is useful as you are not able to do strict comparisons (`===`) between the object and another string.